# Why can't I change my name in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I launch minecraft if I change my name from the launcher, when I go in game my name is not changed.

I've tried exiting out of minecraft and the launcher but it hasn't reset my name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my Minecraft username?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/331777/how-do-i-change-my-minecraft-username)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking the edit profile button and changing that name is not the real name.

To change your *username*:

- Log in to http://account.mojang.com.
- Click `Change`, next to your Minecraft name.
- Enter a new name and enter your password.
- Click the `Change Name` button to confirm.

Your username has been changed.

Now wait a couple minutes (up to 15) and logout and log back into the launcher again.

Comment: ok ill try that

Comment: it did not work

Comment: How are you changing your name? Changing your "profile" name isn't the same.

Comment: @maxdude2074 updated, please try again.

Comment: oh sorry do you know when you click the icon and then in the bottom left of the tab i press edit profile then i change the profile name

Comment: @maxdude2074 that's not changing the name. That's just changing a profile name, which isn't the same as the username. Try following the new instructions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43571/discussion-between-maxdude2074-and-es-i).

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in that Minecraft does not accept the username -=maxdude2074=-.
Minecraft usernames can only contain letters and numbers. Therefore, unless you have an alphanumerical replacement for -= and =-, I suggest not worrying about username changes at present, as there is a cooldown for name changes.

Comment: If the question is "why can't I change my name to `-=maxdude 2074=-`" then "because the name contains disallowed characters" is a perfectly fine answer.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change you name unless you get a new account as far as i know

Comment: You can actually, this is wrong. My username in MC used to be "brikerw", now it's easterlyirk.

Comment: no you can change your name without making a new account i just dont know how to